# Editor texto estilo WYSIWYG

Tags: google-chrome, ckeditor

Boa noite!
Qual editor de texto vocês usam nesse site stack over flow ? Pois estou testando aquele CKeditor e outros no navegador chrome e ambos não permite colar imagens da aérea de transferência para textarea html do site. Não funciona essa opção de colar seja com Ctrl e V ou botão direito. Já esse de vocês funciona em ambos. No firefox ainda funciona esse ckeditor mas chrome e edge não....

Agradeço a atenção de vocês

Aguardo resultados bons pois preciso entender